# Jquery animate get stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

```
        function slideRight() {


            // slide to right
            $("div").animate({
                left: "200px"
            }, 2000, function() {
                slideLeft();
            });
        }

        function slideLeft() {

            // slide to left
            $("div").animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 2000, function() {
                slideRight();
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#start").on("click", function() {
                slideRight();
            });
        });
```

I have TWO divs and I want to move them back and forth at the same time.

```
    <div style="top:100px;"></div>
    <div style="top:300px;"></div>
```

the css code:

```
        div {
            background: yellow;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            left:0px;}
```

However, the animation get stuck and become much slower after each slide. One div is OK. The more divs, the longer the time get stuck. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, your functions call themselves inside another animate function with a never ending cycle which causes delay on each call. Instead I'm stopping the cycle on second function and start again with timeout which breaks the loops and delay too and start again. **[DEMO](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=8cd86a7625bdc2b56cbf7c1787058695)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  slideRight();
});

function slideRight() {
  // slide to right
  $("div").animate({
    'left': "200px"
  }, 1000, slideLeft);
}

function slideLeft() {
  // slide to right
  $("div").animate({
    'left': "0px"
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(slideRight, 1000);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

#second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div><div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: That was it for me :)

Comment: @melvin found the example code and edited the question in case you might need!

Comment: Thanks. Mine function was being called in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding something like :

```
$("div").stop().dequeue().animate({
  ...
```